# Using of the with space

Tags: grammar

When you speak of "outer space", after first mention of it, do you use "the" afterward, or will this be consistently without "the" ?

A: I want to explore space(outer space)
B: "the" space could be very scary.
A: my causine went to "the" space last month.

Comment: Question: is there other words the usage is similar to this, without "the" most of time?

Comment: I can only think of a few: cyberspace, academia, heaven, and hell. It seems to be a pattern: Any (1) place which is (2) non-localized and is (3) not a proper noun but is (4) treated as though it were is probably used the same way.

Comment: @JasonMelançon another noun can be N/nature, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never, ever use the phrase "the space" when referring to outer space, unless you're using it to specify a particular region of outer space, like "the space between galaxies" or "the space around the sun's corona." In this case, "the space" is used exactly the same way it would be when speaking about earthbound spatial relationships, as in "the space between paragraphs," and isn't particular to outer space.

I can't find this rule explicitly written anywhere, but you can read the Wikipedia article on [outer space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_space) and see that they follow this rule.

Comment: Thank you, it is very helpful comment. And the correction below.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Oxford learner's Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/space_1) when referring to outside earth's atmosphere, definition #5, space is unaccountable noun. Thence we conclude that **space** cannot be accompanied by either the definite or the indefinite article.

Comment: Sorry, no, that's not the reason not to use "the." Nothing prevents you from referring to "the" <uncountable noun>. "The fish," "the sheep," "the water," *et cetera* are all fine.

Comment: You shouldn't be sorry, you're right. My bad! @Jason

Comment: Oops! Actually, my bad too. Of course you can count sheep and fish. Air or grass would have been better examples, and they follow the same pattern as water.